# Regular Expression Allow ] [

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to validate a certain username. The username should contain only the following characters `A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ ] [` (with no space). I got the following so far:

```
^[A-Z0-9-_]+$
```

but I want to allow `] [` too.

How do I add them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape those characters within the character class using a backslash.  You should also escape the `-` as it is used as a range separator within a character class (like in `A-Z`):

```
^[A-Z0-9\-_\[\]]+$
```

Note that you technically don't need to escape the `[`, but it won't hurt and I find it easier to remember if I just escape both.

Comment: Or put the `-` first in the character class and it doesn't need escaping. `^[-A-Z0-9_\[\]]+]$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
^[\][A-Z0-9-_]+$
```

It's only necessary to escape the first `]` and even then, if placed at the beginning of the character class, some regular expression engines will not require you to escape it.